# Eclipse mvn project deploy to jboss

Tags: eclipse, deployment, maven-2, jboss

I changed my project to use maven2 (from just plain eclipse dynamic web project) and now I can't do Debug As > Debug on Server (JBoss).

Previously I can just do Debug As > Debug on Server (JBoss) and Eclipse will happily copy the war file into jboss deploy directory and I can debug etc.

Now it seems like eclipse just don't recognize the maven2 project and therefore cannot package the war file? 
I have to deploy it manually using the command line mvn war:war and copy the war file to deploy directory.

What can I do to make Eclipse understand mvn project so I can just do Debug As > Debug on Server?

Eclipse 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/installing-m2eclipse.html) (and the extra *Maven Integration for WTP*). Once installed, **Import...** your webapp project as **Existing Maven Projects** and it will get imported as a dynamic web project.

Comment: It's always there for me, I just didnt see it. Thanks!